# Print generation with f-strings

Tags: python, f-string

Suppose I have:

```
text = ['Apple', 'Banana']
```

I want to use f-string to print items.  My expected output is:

```
items are:
Apple
Banana
```

So far I tried:

```
print(f'items are: {i for i in text}')
```

This prints: `items are: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0BBCB660>`

How can I achieve the desired output? Note that I would need to backslash as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
text = ['Apple', 'Banana']
nl = '\n'
print(f'items are: {nl}{nl.join(text)}')
```

Outputs:

```
items are: 
Apple
Banana
```

The reason why I didn't use \n inside the f-string is because you [can't use backslash inside fstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences).

Comment: This is good, but what if I wanted to achieve the expected output through an iteration?

Comment: Don't think you can use iteration inside f-string without it turning into either a list comprehension or a generator. In any case, printing line after line won't be possible. Why do you want to use an iterator? If you really want, you can just write the for statement inside the join function.